# Is it safe to use only client side validation in intranet applications?

Tags: validation, web

I know that, for obvious reasons, when developing a web application, the data input validation should be always done on the server side. Client side validation is mainly for user experience.
I am now developing am intranet application that will only be used by employees in a controlled environment (accessible only inside our network, used only by employees, only our company's computers, etc). In this scenario, is it safe to use only client side validation?

Comment: I think this can't be answered because it is way too broad. There is no general answer to this, it all depends on you attacker model.

Comment: It depends on employees. If you think that one of them can make a SQL injection and sell company data on market, it better to do on server validation too.

Comment: Primary opinion based, but I'd say no; Employees are not necessarily trustworthy.  Could be sensitive data.  Requirements could change.  The system could be deployed elsewhere.  Employees could make a mistake which generates bad data.  Above all, one should always employ solid programming practices no matter the scenario.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it's never safe. A simple mistake, a virus or whatever may cause your clients to submit invalid data to the server.
If you have to choose, go for server side.

Answer (score 3):

*Do never build software with security flaws on it just because you may trust on the client.*

You should note that your software (now) is for a specific project, but you would likely use it later on others projects, maybe not the full code, but some modules. And in such a case you will have to rethink what is the "good" code and what need to be repaired.

Write good and "safe" code from the moment zero will save you time in the future and headaches too.

It is also hard to think on the *full scope*, because some of your client may have an already vulnerable system. Then, your system will be vulnerable too.

Answer (score 2):

> All input is evil until proven otherwise. That's rule number one. Typically, the moment you forget this rule is the moment you are attacked.

-- [Writing Secure Code, Second Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/5957.aspx), Michael Howard and David LeBlanc

Answer (score 1):

If you trust your employees, then yes, it is safe. Also, consider an evil employee and the worst he could do. However, IMO it's natural that the internal company systems are less safe then those exposed to internet.

Comment: What if the client is of trust, but he is using Windows 95?

Comment: then you can't trust him :-)

Comment: I think this problem is well known as a risk management.

Comment: Hence, you *never* can trust  in a client.

Comment: Do you trust your wife? My wife is a client on my computer. How much effort do you think I spend to protect the computer against her? And, even if she broke something, it would mean just reinstall in a worst case. So, risk vs effort is the value you are looking for. If your employees are well educated friends of you, then why to spend your time to protect the system against them?

Comment: Why to not spend time protecting systems? Why build a vulnerable system *intentionally*? You will only save time in the short term (and maybe not) but you will spend a lot of time tomorrow when you will have information leaked.

Comment: Does it make sense to spend more money to protect your house then the price of the house itself? First, you have to ask how much it woul cost the data leak and then build the protection.

Comment: Good point. I'm agree in that sense, while more sensitive data more secure need to be the system. But please do never write a system with *flaws* intentionally on any case.